# How do I get a value from an xml file by using an xsl file - the files are in different directories

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm a newbie to xml and xsl, I've looked everywhere on the web and I know this is probably a straight forward answer but I can't seem to be able to get it to work. The problem I have is that I have a .xml file and a .xsl file (both are in totally different directories) and I am trying to get the data from the .xml file, but when I view it in IE browser; I just get a blank screen. Please help.

Test.xml

```
<root>
 <tags>abc</tags>
 <tags>def</tags>
 <tags>ghi</tags>
 <tags>jkl</tags>
 <tags>mno</tags>
 <tags>qpr</tags>
</root>
```

Test.xsl

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:variable name="file" select="'C:\Test.xml'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="info" select="document($file)/root/tags"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="tags">
   <xsl:value-of select="$info"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>                

</stylesheet>
```

Output should be:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqr
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. Got it fixed. I was the escape forward slash after file: (3 slashes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well XSLT uses URLs and not file paths so I would start with `<xsl:variable name="file" select="'file:///C:/Test.xml'"/>`. But these days chances are that security restrictions on local file system access hamper free navigation and access across it so make sure you check the error console whether it shows any messages.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so fast. I've changed the file variable, but I still receive a blank screen. @Martin Honnen

Comment: Well tell us some details of your setup, where is the primary input file coming from (HTTP or file system), and what does the error console after hitting F12 and reloading show?

Comment: Both files are on my computer, just different folders. Didn't know about F12 (just tried it, its just a blank screen). I'm basically just using notepad++ and internet explorer.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide minimal but complete samples allowing others to reproduce the problem. For instance you have `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:for-each select="tags">`, if the primary input document does not have any `tags` root element then that template will not output anything. You haven't shown the primary input XML at all so we can only guess or make suggestions on how to debug that, but information like "blank" screen does not allow us to tell where the problem is.